# Error in Slim 3 because of mismatch in request uri & request method

Tags: php, rest, restful-architecture, restful-url, slim-3

I'm using Slim 3 Framework as my backend and a small self-written frontend (jQuery). In my frontend I have ajax commands to call my REST server.
Now I'm facing the problem that I can't use `DELETE` on my client because it is not matching the HTTP request method (`GET`).

```
405 Method not allowed. Must be one of: GET, PUT
```

The official documentation says said it is not allowed by default:

> If your Slim Framework application has a route that matches the
>   current HTTP request URI but NOT the HTTP request method, the
>   application invokes its Not Allowed handler and returns a HTTP/1.1 405
>   Not Allowed response to the HTTP client.

Now I could use `GET` or `PUT` but that is not possibly because I already have those routes declared for other actions.

> Slim Application Error: 
>   The application could not run because of the following error: 
>   Details 
>   Type:  FastRoute\BadRouteException 
>   Message:  Static route /api/v1/folders/ is shadowed by previously defined     variable route /api/v1/folders/(.*) for method GET

```
// Folder routes
$this->group('/folders', function () {
    $this->get('[/{params:.*}]', 'FolderController:index');
    $this->post('', 'FolderController:create');
    $this->put('[/{params:.*}]', 'FolderController:update');
    $this->delete('/[/{params:.*}]', 'FolderController:delete');
})->add('AuthenticateMiddleware');
```

Could you please give me an advice on how to solve this? Isn't this a general problem in the REST-world so to speak, because I guess many frameworks act like Slim 3 and throw a `405 Method not allowed` error in such particular situation where you want to use `DELETE` but can't because the click in the browser is `GET`?

Comment: Is the failing request happening when you click on a link? <a></a> ? The request method has to be `DELETE` in order for Slim to invoke the right controller. Also note that your delete route has an extra `[`

Comment: @AlexandruUngureanu You have eagle eyes because after I removed `[` it started working with my ajax `DELETE`. Please make a small post and I'll accept your answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment:

> Is the failing request happening when you click on a link? `<a></a>` ? The request method has to be `DELETE` in order for Slim to invoke the right controller. Also note that your delete route has an extra `[`

Good luck !